# Continued fractions proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, continued-fractions

Let $b_1=1$ and $$b_n=1+\frac{1}{1+b_{n-1}}$$ for $n\ge 2$.  Note that $b_n \ge 1$ for all $n$ in $\mathbb N$. ($\mathbb N$ represents the positive integers)

Show that $b_{2k-1}^2<2$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$.

Any ideas on how to start?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try an inductive argument. For $b_1$ this certainly holds. Suppose the result holds for $b_{2n-1}$. Consider
$$b_{2n+1} = 1+\frac{1}{1+b_{2n}} = 1+\frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{1+b_{2n-1}}}$$
From the inductive hypothesis, we know that $b_{2n-1} < \sqrt{2}$ or equivalently
$$b_{2n+1} < 1 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}} = \frac{4+3\sqrt{2}}{3+2\sqrt{2}}$$
The latter expression is in fact $\sqrt{2}$ disguised. To see this, note that
$$\frac{4+3\sqrt{2}}{3 + 2\sqrt{2}} - \sqrt{2} = \frac{4 + 3\sqrt{2} - 3\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}{3 + 2\sqrt{2}} = 0$$

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Put another way, each convergent $\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ appears as numerator and denominator in the left-hand column of 
 $$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  1  &  2  \\
   1   &  1  
\end{array} 
  \right)^n, 
  $$
as in 
 $$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  1  &  2  \\
   1   &  1  
\end{array} 
  \right)^2 \; = \;
  \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  3  &  4  \\
   2   &  3  
\end{array} 
  \right),
  $$
then
 $$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  1  &  2  \\
   1   &  1  
\end{array} 
  \right)^3 \; = \;
  \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  7  &  10  \\
   5   &  7  
\end{array} 
  \right),
  $$
and
 $$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  1  &  2  \\
   1   &  1  
\end{array} 
  \right)^4 \; = \;
  \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  17  &  24  \\
   12   &  17  
\end{array} 
  \right),
  $$

and so on.

And so we get  $$  x_n^2 \,- \, 2 \, y_n^2 \, = (-1)^n,  $$ because
 $$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  1  &  2  \\
   1   &  1  
\end{array} 
  \right)^n \; = \;
  \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  x_n  &  2 y_n  \\
   y_n   &  x_n  
\end{array} 
  \right)
  $$
and we are comparing determinants.

Answer (score 1):

It’s clear that each $b_n$ is rational, so let $b_n=\dfrac{p_n}{q_n}$ for some integers $p_n$ and $q_n$. The recurrence is then

$$\begin{align*}
b_{n+1}&=1+\frac1{1+b_n}\\
&=\frac{2+b_n}{1+b_n}\\
&=\frac{2+\frac{p_n}{q_n}}{1+\frac{p_n}{q_n}}\\
&=\frac{p_n+2q_n}{p_n+q_n}\;,\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

with $p_1=q_1=1$.

The sequence $\left\langle\dfrac{p_n}{q_n}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$ may be recognized from $(1)$ as the sequence of convergents of the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt 2$, [which is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Periodic_continued_fractions) $[1;\overline{2}]$. This can also be seen directly from the original recurrence, as

$$1+\frac1{2+\frac1x}=1+\frac1{1+\left(1+\frac1x\right)}\;;\tag{2}$$

in particular, if $1+\frac1x$ is the $n$-th convergent to $\sqrt 2$, $(2)$ gives the $(n+1)$-st convergent, and we have $$b_{n+1}=1+\frac1{1+b_n}\;.$$

General facts about continued fractions ensure that the convergents are alternately less than and greater than $\sqrt 2$, and since $b_1<\sqrt2$, it is the odd-indexed convergents that are less than $\sqrt 2$.